# Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 and Entity Framework walkthrough

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I am in the process of evaluating Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 and looking for possible replacements for current our data access layer.

The Entity Framework looks like a promising replacement to the data retrieval functionality in our applications.

Does anyone have a great walk-through/tutorial that demonstrates how to use the Entity Framework from soup to nuts?

Answer (score 1):

The definitive learning guide in my opinion is Julie Lerman's book, ["Programming Entity Framework](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520298)".

For online tutorials, take a look at:

- [Short tutorial from Stefan Cruysberghs](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET12)
- [Zeeshan Hirani's EF Learning guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/12/08/my-christmas-present-to-the-entity-framework-community.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4 Training Kit - October Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=752CB725-969B-4732-A383-ED5740F02E93&displaylang=en)